# Is it possible to alternate sheet number in a drag function, for example: highlight the cell, drag the corner to alternate, but only target file path

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to perform this function to create a summary file. I've attached different excel sheets by copying their file path into the cells. By aiming at specific cells of data in each sheet (the same column, same # of cells) I can create a summary, by inserting their file path into rows on my summary workbook. The challenge here is trying to avoid having to use the "Find and Replace" function to change the name of the sheet repeatedly. I will be connecting 300 sheets as a max. I honestly doubt I'll have such a big summary, but I need to make a safeguard for other users who aren't as savvy. I can't think of a way to develop a macro to do so, or find anything in the "Fill" command that would be of assistance.

If there might be a better way of doing this that doesn't go this route, I would be open to that as well.

Comment: Honestly I'm unable to understand your exact need,, tell me are U trying to collect only File name (along with path) in one WB,,, or trying to SUMMARIZE their data ?? Please [edit] your post and make it clear & avoid vote to close this post !!

Answer (score 0):

**INDIRECT method: requires opened workbooks**

You can use

```
=INDIRECT("'[full path or URL incl filename]" & "Sheetname" & "'!" & "A1")
```

Fortunately for this to work the file that INDIRECT is referencing must be open in Excel. This is because Excel cannot create, manage and sync a permanent file link - which I don't think will work for you.

**FORMULA VIEW method: Find-and-replace text into a formula**

There is a neat trick that you can use, not fully automated, but easy enough to do:
Put file path and name in B1, sheetname in C1 and reference (as text) in D1 then in E1:

```
="#'["&B1&"]"&C1&"'!"&D1
```

This creates a text string that looks like a formula, starting with a # instead of = sign.
To convert this to an active formula, first select the whole column E and copy-paste-as-value to F. Now hit CTRL+` to enable formula view. Select column F, hit CTRL+H for Find and Replace, and "replace all" # signs with = signs. Hit CTRL+`` again and you should be good to go.

**Google Sheets method**

Google sheets IMPORTRANGE works pretty well. Every sub-file gets an unique URL on your google drive. You can even share these sub-files with people to edit and update. The summary/master can combine the URL strings (to each file), plus the sheet name and reference in much the same way as above. You can then share that master sheet, perhaps as read-only to other users.

**FULLY AUTOMATED VBA method**

To use fully variable cell links (like with INDIRECT), but without required for the workbooks to be open, require VBA. Have a google for the "Harlan Grove PULL function" or similar "VBA indirect link to external workbook without file open".