# How can I pull specific cells from multiple files into columns in separate worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 40-50 workbooks that each have about 5 columns and 30 rows that I need to reorganize into a several worksheets within a single workbook. To do so, I need to pull specific cells from each file. I've created a simplified example of what I want to do below.

Let's say my roommates and I are keeping track of our monthly spending, with a separate workbook file for each month. That spreadsheet might look like this:

| January |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Groceries | Utilities | Beer |
| Matt | $150 | $130 | $200 |
| Bob | $175 | $80 | $50 |
| Peggy | $85 | $35 | $0 |

I have six months of these, and I want to combine them into a single workbook separate tabs for each category. Groceries would like this:

|  | January | February | March | April | May | June |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Matt | $150 | $140 | $124 | $101 | $142 | $66 |
| Bob | $175 | $137 | $80 | $124 | $50 | $111 |
| Peggy | $85 | $117 | $130 | $75 | $83 | $126 |

There would be a separate tabs for Utilities and Beer. How would I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. The tables looked fine in the previewer. Are they broken for anyone else?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately, the tables did not came out right. But you can take screenshots from your spreadsheet and paste them in your question as images.

Comment: I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

**The manual way:**

Open all 50 spreadsheets, and copy each sheet into the master sheet. If all the sheets follow the same format you can even use [3D cell references](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6#:%7E:text=Click%20the%20tab%20for%20the,formula%2C%20and%20then%20press%20ENTER.), once all the sheets are copied into the master.
Or if you need to maintain a live link to the original file, you can simply have say the master and linked workbooks open, then edit a cell in the master, type = character and then click the cell in the linked workbook.

Unfortunately this remains a very time consuming thing to do with 50 workbooks. The problem is Excel is quite strict about security. You cannot simply put a list of filenames in column A, then link into those with a formula. In essence you could then create a workbook that can steal info from any file on a computer. Therefor Excel mostly requires you to open the workbook in order to authorise and establish the link. That being said:

**A few automate ways**

Have a look [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/11/08/merge-multiple-excel-files-into-one/) for a method to do this in VBA, or with an add-in.

**A slightly less tedious alternative**

Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1636252/how-to-create-a-source-and-destination-worksheets-in-excel/1637626#1637626) at a previous answer of mine for methods to access external workbooks.

There is a workaround for the above mentioned security restriction. List all the filenames in say column A. Then build up the "formula" as text in the next cell, in the format #'path[filename]Sheetname'!A1 - but as text in a cell. Then copy paste the result as values in the next column, then search and replace # for = which turns all those text values into live and linked formulae. You might still need to have all the workbooks open (at least once? maybe?) but it saves a whole lot of clicks. See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1645983/is-it-possible-to-alternate-sheet-number-in-a-drag-function-for-example-highli/1649089#1649089).

Comment: Thanks for this. This should help immensely.

Comment: Great stuff! Kindly do checkmark the answer so others may know it has been solved. -M